# hide nircmd gui in python call

Tags: python, windows, command-line

Hello I was creating a remote operation tool which uses `nircmd`.**The command is performed but the application pauses at this screen**
 [image]

Is there any way to get rid of this screen? [nircmd.exe is copied in my windows directory]

The code:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost',5000))
s.listen(5)
c,addr=s.accept()
c.send("Enter command for nircmd: ".encode())
cmd=c.recv(1024)
cmd=cmd.decode()
cmd="nircmd "+str(cmd)
c.send(cmd.encode())          

exe=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=exe.communicate()
out=out+err
c.sendall(out)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a quick look at the utility you mentioned.

Seems that window only pops up instead of any kind of error message if you give a wrong command line option, so check what you're sending.

Seems ther's also a command line only version in the zip file (`nircmdc`), maybe you should use that instead.

Comment: than you very much. I forgot there isa commandline version in the zip file. Your answer has reminded me of it and bingo! the application works :D